# Javascript not working in edge, but fine in Firefox, Chrome

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I wrote a JavaScript function to get the current logged in user from any page on our SharePoint site and add it to a redirect call so I can make apps that only logged in SP users can access.

```
 <script>

 function init(){
 var divv = document.getElementById('SuiteNavUserName').innerHTML;
 var UN;
 UN = "http://subsite.comapny.org/application/from_sharepoint.aspx?usr=" + divv;
 window.location = UN;
 }
 t = setTimeout("init()",3000);
 </script>
```

Unfortunately, edge never redirects. Any idea what Edge does not like about my script? I'd test it, but the PC I'm on is running win 7 and thus no Edge to play with.

Comment: try window.location.href

Comment: try also to add only the name of the callback function: `setTimeout(init,3000)`

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to pass the function instead of string for example `setTimeout(() => init(), 3000)`

Comment: I tried window.location.href and Edge was happy. Thanks V. Volkov

Answer (score 0):

add .href to window.location to get: window.location.href